# rightBarButtonItem not displaying on View

Tags: ios, uinavigationbar, uinavigationitem

I'm trying to programmatically implement a title and rightBarButtonItem in a view with the following code but the title and button are not being displayed, everything else including the navigationBar and tabBarItem properties work. Can't figure out where I am going wrong.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
  [super viewDidLoad];

  self.navigationController.navigationBar.barTintColor = COLOR_NAVBAR_BACKGROUND;
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.tintColor = COLOR_NAVBAR_BUTTON;
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.titleTextAttributes = @{NSForegroundColorAttributeName:COLOR_NAVBAR_TITLE};
  self.navigationController.navigationBar.translucent = NO;

  self.tabBarItem.title = nil;
  [self.tabBarItem setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_group"]];
  [self.tabBarItem setSelectedImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"tab_group"]];
  self.tabBarItem.title = @"Group";

  self.title = @"Group";

  self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"New" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(actionNew)];
}
```

Comment: This question was asked before and I am implementing the solution to that question but the solution does not work for me.

Comment: what problem you face Now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check and Try

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];



    UIBarButtonItem *rigthButtonClicked=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(rigthButtonClicked:)];

     [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:rigthButtonClicked];


     UIBarButtonItem *leftButtonClicked=[[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemAdd target:self action:@selector(leftButtonClicked:)];

 [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:leftButtonClicked];
}
```

Two Button Here

```
-(void)rigthButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
{

    NSLog(@"RigthButtonClicked");
}

-(void)leftButtonClicked:(UIBarButtonItem *)button
{


    NSLog(@"leftButtonClicked");
}
```

Comment: Still getting the same result when I implement your solution: the button is not being displayed.

Comment: You use navigation Controller

Comment: My bad... I forgot to implement the navigation controller.